# Pdftron setup, getting Http 404 file not found error while reference index.html for react app

Tags: reactjs, installation, build, public, pdftron

When trying to integrate PDFtron into react app...I am getting a Http 404 file not found error. Looks like it is not finding correct reference to index.html.The public folder along with core and UI get copied to my build folder after I run npm run build. But I still get Http 404 file not error. Appreciate any help.

Updated: I do not have error getting pdftron running on localhost but when trying to serve it on the server..Webviewer/lib/ui/index.html 404 error is encountered. My scenario is to use CRM dynamics webapp which calls custom react app integrated with PDFTRON. Basically rending Webviewer on click of an icon button. And after npm run build and bundling the package ..I upload the main application index.html through WebResources in CRM dynamics. I have used gulp tool to merge changes from main index.html and Webviewer/lib/ui/index.html. But it is not able to find the PDftron index.html.
My case is integrating pdftron with custom react application with CRM dynamics. Please suggest resolution. I can only upload single Webresource for the tab on CRM dynamics.

Comment: Please provide full javascript console output, and browser network panel. make sure to show the 404.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Rose, it looks like WebViewer may not be step up correctly, have you had a chance to take a look at our Reactjs sample app here https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-react-sample? If you can provide more details of your setup up it will help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Hello I updated the post with more details. Any suggestions to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is `lib` folder accessible via the path in the browser you are passing in WebViewer options object?

For example, if my lib in `public/lib/ui/index.html` I should access it in `localhost:3000/lib/ui/index.html`.

Comment: Hello Andrey..please see the update. The 404 index.html is encountered with integrating PdFtron with react app in CRM dynamics. Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: does PDFtron provide an option to integrate with CRM 365 dynamics?

Comment: Thank you for the update! One thing I suspect is the [mime types](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/faq/blazor-integration-issues/). Here is a [detailed guide](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/sharepoint/) for Sharepoint/MS Stack. I would cross-check it to make sure nothing is missed.